# Django 2.0 Model Admin links using allow_tags don't work

Tags: python, django

I wanted to learn Django and researching I found this interesting book [Django By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1784391913). One of the problems is that the book is using Django 1.8.6 and I am trying to use the v2.0, so from time to time I came with some error that you can resolved really easy. But when I tried to create a Shop with the code and instructions from the book I came with this problem:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/364H2.png)

The code that I used was this one:

view.py

```
@staff_member_required
def admin_order_detail(request, order_id):
     order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
     return render(request, 'admin/orders/order/detail.html', {'order': order})

@staff_member_required
def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    html = render_to_string('orders/order/pdf.html', {'order': order})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="order_{}.pdf"'.format(order.id)
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response,
                                       stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/pdf.css')])
    return response
```

urls.py

```
re_path(r'admin/order/(?P<order_id>\d+)/$', views.admin_order_detail, name='admin_order_detail'),
re_path(r'^admin/order/(?P<order_id>\d+)/pdf/$', views.admin_order_pdf, name='admin_order_pdf'),
```

admin.py

```
def order_detail(obj):
    return '<a href="{}">View</a>'.format(reverse('orders:admin_order_detail',
                                              args=[obj.id]))
order_detail.allow_tags = True

def order_pdf(obj):
    return '<a href="{}">PDF</a>'.format(reverse('orders:admin_order_pdf',
                                             args=[obj.id]))
order_pdf.allow_tags = True
order_pdf.short_description = 'PDF bill'
```

I also have the html files on the correct directory but I don't think that is the problem. So if anyone knows where is where I am wrong I appreciated.

Thanks :3

Comment: What exactly is the question / problem?

Comment: Try removing the indent from `order_detail.allow_tags` and `order_pdf.allow_tags` They should be indented on the same level as the function definition.

Comment: My bad, in the real code they are. Let me edit it.